# php checkbox input update mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, input

If somebody can point me out on the right direction 
would be highly appreciated. For some reason the database 
is not updated, based on the input received from the checkbox. 
Below is a snippet of the code that I use to accomplish this 
task.

I do not know why, the content in the database stays the 
same unchanged either way if the checkbox is checked or not.

this is the html code

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="Jack" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
        <input type="checkbox" name="drink" value="1"> <span>Did you drink today?</span>            
        <input type="submit" name="post_content"  value="Submit">

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

this is the php

```
<?php           

if ( isset($_POST['button']) && ( ($_POST['drink']) == 1 ) ) {

    $post_id = $_POST['Jack'];
    $my_post = array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_content' => 'Just whiskey'
                );
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
; ?>
```

Thanks a lot for any input you guys will do.

Comment: You don't have an input named `button` - That entire conditional statement is based on it. Hint: `post_content`

Comment: You should use if(isset($_POST['drink'])) { }. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an input named `button`

Your code's execution's success is based on that entire conditional statement.

```
if ( isset($_POST['button']) && ( ($_POST['drink']) == 1 ) ) {...}
                   ^^^^^^
```

it should be:

```
if ( isset($_POST['post_content']) && ( ($_POST['drink']) == 1 ) ){...}
```

based on your submit button's name:

```
<input type="submit" name="post_content"  value="Submit">
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which will throw an `Undefined index button...` warning.

Answer (score 1):

instead of  `$_POST['button']` you should check for `$_POST['post_content']` because there is no button on your page.you should use `error_reporting`.

Answer (score 0):

if not checked `$_POST['drink']` will not be set. so check if it is checked or not .

```
$drink = isset($_POST['drink']) ? $_POST['drink'] : 0;
```

something like that and then

```
if ( isset($_POST['button']) && ( $drink' == 1 ) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="Jack" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="drink">
        <input type="checkbox" class='check_or_not'> <span>Did you drink today?</span>            
        <input type="submit" name="post_content"  value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
 $(".check_or_not").click(function(){
     if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
        $(this).prev().val(1);
     }else{
        $(this).prev().val(0);
     }
 })
</script>
```

change your html like above,check box will not pass the value like what you excepted..i suppose you are using jquery